# Aggregate multiple rows into new single long row of data

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate

I have a database with many rows of data per "case".  Each "case" has a unique ID, but each row has a "multiple-choice-element" and a "value". Obviously there is a new row every time the user selects one of the multiple choice elements(mce) and the new value too.  The unique ID is like a linchpin holding all of the rows together as a common element for this instance

The data is as follows:

```
UniqueID  Value      Text       Username     Contact
--------------------------------------------------
123456    No Sound   Horn       Johnson      0788
123456    Broken     Headlight  Johnson      0788
123456    Broken     Windscreen Johnson      0788
```

I am looking to keep just one row of data, their user details, the key (unique ID), and then have multiple columns for each mce and each value.

```
UniqueID Username  Contact   Text  Value      Text      Value   Text       Value
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456   Johnson   0788      Horn  No Sound   Headlight Broken  Windscreen Broken
```

I have done this using an update statement for each mce based on the Unique ID so far, but it's a bit clunky and long winded as a stored-procedure and can take quite a bit of time to run.

Can anyone suggest a better way please.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your table structure, some existing data, and a sample of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Thanks, currently(simplified): UNiqueID, Value, MCE, USername, Contact...

Comment: Try editing the post to include it: look at the way this post does it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650719/how-can-i-unpivot-columns-into-rows) if you need help.

Comment: @AHiggins - thankyou for your direction, I have learned something today at least!

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 2: I wasn't even sure this was possible, but I think I've found a way.  Unfortunately, it's extremely hacky, and since you never posted your RDBMS tag, I don't even know if it will work for you.

I don't particularly like the solution, as I said - it feels clumsy to me, but it does work and I don't have any more time to dedicate to this issue.  Unless someone else can figure out a way to make it work more efficiently, this is the best I can do for you.  Note that I create and reference a temp table called #Numbers - you'll need this to stay in your query.  Also note that you might end up with more columns than you want, but that will have to stay.

The following script will allow you to pivot two columns, preserving the relationship between a distinct value in column #1 (Txt) and multiple values in column #2 (Value)

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (UniqueID INT, Value varchar(10), Txt varchar(10), Username varchar(10), Contact INT)
INSERT INTO #Data (UniqueID, Value, Txt, Username, Contact) 

SELECT 123456, 'No Sound', 'Horn', 'Johnson', 0788 UNION
SELECT 123456, 'Broken', 'Headlight', 'Johnson', 0788 UNION
SELECT 123456, 'Smashed', 'Headlight', 'Johnson', 0788 UNION
SELECT 123456, 'Shattered', 'Headlight', 'Johnson', 0788 UNION
SELECT 123456, 'Busted', 'Headlight', 'Johnson', 0788 UNION
SELECT 123456, 'Inop', 'Brake', 'Johnson', 0788 

DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max)
DECLARE @vpivot_list AS varchar(max) -- Leave NULL for COALESCE technique
DECLARE @vselect_list AS varchar(max) -- Leave NULL for COALESCE technique
DECLARE @tpivot_list AS varchar(max) -- Leave NULL for COALESCE technique
DECLARE @tselect_list AS varchar(max) -- Leave NULL for COALESCE technique



CREATE TABLE #Numbers (Number INT) 
;WITH NumberSequence( Number ) AS
  (
    SELECT 1 as Number
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Number + 1
    FROM NumberSequence
    WHERE Number < 100
  )
INSERT INTO #Numbers (Number)
SELECT Number FROM NumberSequence




SELECT 
    @vpivot_list = COALESCE(@vpivot_list + ', ', '') + '[' + TxtValCombinations + ']'
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
        'T' + CAST(Txt.Number AS VARCHAR(5)) + '_' + 
        'V' + CAST(Val.Number AS VARCHAR(5))  AS TxtValCombinations
    FROM 
        #Numbers Txt
         INNER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT MAX(CountTxt) MaxCountTxt
            FROM
              (
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Txt) CountTxt
                FROM #Data
                GROUP BY UniqueID 
              ) cv
          ) MaxCountTxt ON 
            Txt.Number <= MaxCountTxt.MaxCountTxt
         INNER JOIN 
        #Numbers Val ON 
            Val.Number < 
              (
                SELECT MAX(CountValue) MaxCountValue
                FROM
                  (
                    SELECT COUNT(Value) CountValue
                    FROM #Data
                    GROUP BY UniqueID, Txt
                  ) cv
              )
  ) PossibleValues


SELECT 
    @tpivot_list = COALESCE(@tpivot_list + ', ', '') + '[' + TxtCombinations + ']'
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
        'T' + CAST(Txt.Number AS VARCHAR(5)) AS TxtCombinations
    FROM 
        #Numbers Txt
         INNER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT MAX(CountTxt) MaxCountTxt
            FROM
              (
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Txt) CountTxt
                FROM #Data
                GROUP BY UniqueID 
              ) cv
          ) MaxCountTxt ON 
            Txt.Number <= MaxCountTxt.MaxCountTxt
  ) PossibleValues

SELECT @vselect_list = STUFF(
  (
    SELECT',' + 
        'T' + CAST(Txt.Number AS VARCHAR(5)) + '_' + 
        'V' + CAST(Val.Number AS VARCHAR(5))  --AS TxtValCombinations
    FROM 
        #Numbers Txt
         INNER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT MAX(CountTxt) MaxCountTxt
            FROM
              (
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Txt) CountTxt
                FROM #Data
                GROUP BY UniqueID 
              ) cv
          ) MaxCountTxt ON 
            Txt.Number <= MaxCountTxt.MaxCountTxt
         INNER JOIN 
        #Numbers Val ON 
            Val.Number < 
              (
                SELECT MAX(CountValue) MaxCountValue
                FROM
                  (
                    SELECT COUNT(Value) CountValue
                    FROM #Data
                    GROUP BY UniqueID, Txt
                  ) cv
              )
    ORDER BY Txt.Number, Val.Number
     FOR XML PATH(''), type
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

 SELECT @tselect_list = STUFF(
  (

    SELECT TxtValCombinations
    FROM 
     (
        SELECT',MAX(' + 
            'T' + CAST(Txt.Number AS VARCHAR(5)) + '_' + 
            'V' + CAST(Val.Number AS VARCHAR(5)) + ') AS '+ 
            'T' + CAST(Txt.Number AS VARCHAR(5)) + '_' + 
            'V' + CAST(Val.Number AS VARCHAR(5))  AS TxtValCombinations
        FROM 
            #Numbers Txt
             INNER JOIN 
              (
                SELECT MAX(CountTxt) MaxCountTxt
                FROM
                  (
                    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Txt) CountTxt
                    FROM #Data
                    GROUP BY UniqueID 
                  ) cv
              ) MaxCountTxt ON 
                Txt.Number <= MaxCountTxt.MaxCountTxt
             INNER JOIN 
            #Numbers Val ON 
                Val.Number < 
                  (
                    SELECT MAX(CountValue) MaxCountValue
                    FROM
                      (
                        SELECT COUNT(Value) CountValue
                        FROM #Data
                        GROUP BY UniqueID, Txt
                      ) cv
                  )

        UNION ALL 
        SELECT',MAX(' + 
            'T' + CAST(Txt.Number AS VARCHAR(5)) +') AS T' + CAST(Txt.Number AS VARCHAR(5))  --AS TxtValCombinations
        FROM 
            #Numbers Txt
             INNER JOIN 
              (
                SELECT MAX(CountTxt) MaxCountTxt
                FROM
                  (
                    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Txt) CountTxt
                    FROM #Data
                    GROUP BY UniqueID 
                  ) cv
              ) MaxCountTxt ON 
                Txt.Number <= MaxCountTxt.MaxCountTxt

     ) s
        ORDER BY TxtValCombinations
     FOR XML PATH(''), type
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')



SET @sql = '

SELECT UniqueID, Username, Contact, ' + @tselect_list + '
FROM 
  (

    SELECT UniqueID, Username, Contact, Txt, tPIVOT_CODE, ' + @vselect_list + '
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT b.UniqueID, Value, Username, Contact, Txt, tPIVOT_CODE, vPIVOT_CODE
        FROM 
              (
                SELECT 
                    Data.UniqueID,  
                    Data.Username, 
                    Data.Contact, 
                    Data.Txt,
                    ''T'' + CAST(grpTxt.TxtNum AS VARCHAR(5)) AS tPIVOT_CODE, 
                    Data.Value,
                    ''T'' + CAST(grpTxt.TxtNum AS VARCHAR(5)) + ''_V'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Data.UniqueID, Data.Txt ORDER BY Data.Value) AS VARCHAR(4)) vPIVOT_CODE 
                FROM 
                    #Data Data
                     INNER JOIN 
                      (
                        SELECT UniqueID, Txt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY Txt) AS TxtNum
                        FROM #Data
                        GROUP BY UniqueID, Txt
                      ) grpTxt ON 
                        Data.UniqueID = grpTxt.UniqueID AND
                        Data.Txt = grpTxt.Txt

              ) b
      ) vp
    PIVOT (
        MIN(Value)
        FOR vPIVOT_CODE IN (
            ' + @vpivot_list + '
        )
    ) AS vpvt
  ) tp
PIVOT (
    MIN(Txt)
    FOR tPIVOT_CODE IN (
        ' + @tpivot_list + '
    )
) AS tpvt
GROUP BY UniqueID, UserName, Contact
ORDER BY UniqueID, UserName, Contact
'


--PRINT @sql
--PRINT @tselect_list
--PRINT @vpivot_list
EXEC (@sql)

DROP TABLE #Data
DROP TABLE #Numbers
```

Comment: Thankyou @ahiggins My actual data has 18 columns of defects to be pivoted, am I right in saying that the =sql part is static and the =pivot_list is the parts to be aggregated?  Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Yes, pivot_list is the columns being aggregated - in this code, it basically just reads r1, r2, r3, etc. all the way up to the maximum number of values for a specific uniqueID.  Are you saying that you have 18 total columns that need to be aggregated, rather than just the two (Value + Txt) in the example, or are you saying that Value + Txt can have up to 18 rows???

Comment: There Will be only one Text column, but the multiple choice element (Value) can be selected up to 18 times on the form that is submitted writing to the database, meaning that there could be up to 18 rows in the first instance, the only difference on each row being the value field, which is proving hard to show results for unless you know the uniqueID to select by, so that's the thinking behind slimming the 18 rows down to 1 longer row.  So, Txt + (18 x value)

Comment: So, in your desired output you could have UniqueID, Txt, Value1, Value2, etc.?  Or are you looking for UniqueID, Txt1, Value11, Value12, Txt2, Value21, Value22?

Comment: Yes, Unique ID, Txt, Value1, Value2, Value3...Value18.  The "update" I have been using input the UniqueID, then updated each of the columns to suit.  Would this be easier run inside SSIS do you think.

Comment: @user3735855, I updated my code to match what you just described, try the new version.

Comment: Thankyou @Ahiggins, row 2 is much better, could we get all of these rows amalgamated, so that we have 123456, Johnson, 788, Brake, Inop, Headlight, Broken, Smashed, Shattered, Busted, Horn, No Sound, Windscreen, cracked, door, dented etc all the way to potentially 18 columns , and then it would go onto another row of data (for a different unique ref), with the same sort of data stuff in there, etc.  Thankyou for your time and effort with this.

Comment: New edit posted, this is about as much time as I can dedicate to this issue but hopefully this will address your problem.

Comment: Thankyou @ahiggins I really appreciate the time that you have spent - you've been a great help.

Comment: You're very welcome, @user3735855.  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.