# How can I UNPIVOT columns into rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following table `#document_fields`

```
id   x   y    z
------------------
1  foo  bar  baz
2  one  two  three
3  aaa  bbb  ccc
4  123  456  789
```

The number of columns may vary, as do the column names. I need to pivot the columns into rows like this:

```
id  field value
---------------
1   x     foo
1   y     bar
1   z     baz
2   x     one
2   y     two
2   z     three
.
.
3   z     789
```

I'm trying to understand the way pivoting in SQL Server works but can't get any further than this:

```
select 
      *
into
      #document_fields_pivot
from (
      select * from (
            select *
            from #document_fields
      ) t
      pivot (
            -- ??
      ) p
  ) tbl
```

Can anyone help me to finish this query / explain me pivoting? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called `UNPIVOT` and done like so:

```
select id,field,value from
#document_fields
unpivot
(
 value
 for field in (x,y,z)
) as u
order by id,field
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/YEWC31346)

Comment: Thanks! I get an error though: The type of column "y" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list. I read in another thread this is because all the columns have to be of same datatype and length. Is there, in theis example, a quick way to iterate through the columns (x, y and z but as said there might be hundreds more) and convert them all to the same datadate and length?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. However, I am curious why you would have this kind of structure in your table. I mean you shouldn't have text and numbers in a single column right? Or am I missing something simple?

Comment: Yes it's simple really :) A client wants a data dump in this format for easy filtering in excel. So this script is just generating that excel. Of course in reality all is stored as it should be :)

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Component table (ComponentId INT,Descr VARCHAR(10),Descr1 VARCHAR(10),Descr2 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Component (ComponentId,Descr,Descr1,Descr2)values (1,'foo','bar','baz')
INSERT INTO @Component (ComponentId,Descr,Descr1,Descr2)values (2,'one','two','three')
INSERT INTO @Component (ComponentId,Descr,Descr1,Descr2)values (3,'aaa','bbb','ccc')
INSERT INTO @Component (ComponentId,Descr,Descr1,Descr2)values (3,'123','456','789')


   select
      ComponentId,Field
   from @Component P

 UNPIVOT
 (
   Field
   FOR Value
   IN (
    [Descr],[Descr1],[Descr2]
   )
 ) PivotTable;
```

Comment: Thanks! I get an error though: `The type of column "y" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list`. I read in another thread this is because all the columns have to be of same datatype and length. Is there, in theis example, a quick way to iterate through the columns (x, y and z but as said there might be hundreds more) and convert them all to the same datadate and length?

Comment: convert or cast make sense.based on sample data you provided i wrote query..just modify according to your requirement